# Determine the size of object without its virtual table pointers

Tags: c++, sizeof, memory-layout, vptr

Is there a generic way (not platform dependent) to get at compile time the size of a class object in the memory, without counting the vtable pointers?

Comment: What's wrong with `sizeof`? It does not include the size of vtable, only the size of a pointer to vtable, if any.

Comment: Subtraction? What if there is more than one?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what for?

Comment: A vtable is already something platform-dependent. The C++ standard does not mandate the use of vtables to implement virtual functions.

Comment: You need to consult the description of the memory layout of object on your platform, if there is one, to know the location of the vptrs. You will learn of the layout of virtual base, what a primary base is, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking for a portable way:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  struct S 
  {
    DataMemberType1 dataMember1;
    ...
    DataMemberTypeN dataMemberN;
  } m;

public:
  static const size_t MemberSize = sizeof(S);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this is 100% portable and `sizeof(MyClass) - sizeof(S)` will always be exactly equal to the size of the vpointer?

Comment: @Neil: My solution avoids the implementation specific details. Have a short look at "How are C++ objects laid out in memory?" [link](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#layout-obj).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.. what if there is padding?

Comment: @Neil: Yes, you can expect padding, but it should make no difference as you have the same padding in 'class' as in 'struct'

Comment: What about the padding present in MyClass but not in m?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sizeof` on this `class`, it doesn't include size of the `vtable` just the pointer.

Comment: @PaulEvans Your answer is false for any object that has virtual functions (any object actually containing a vtable.) http://ideone.com/7y48aO

Comment: @JonathanMee The answer is correct; class instances contains a vptr (short for vtable pointer) **not** a vtable (table of function pointers for virtual functions of the class + RTTI info + virtual bases offset)